# I can't open manage.py

Tags: python, django, windows, command-prompt, django-manage.py

On the command prompt, (Windows 10) I created a virtual environment, I then created a new project, I installed django in the virtual environment using pip. Then decided to run the command

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

To run djangos web server,
This returned with

> ```
> "...can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
> ```

I did see a similar question to this on this platform but it seems to only apply to those using linux. Where answers specify to use the ls command, which is not applicable on Windows command prompt. I have tried this multiple times but i just can't open

```
manage.py
```

Comment: first you need to search manage.py on your drives, then coy and paste its address and put it on command line like this: 

python "youraddress/manage.py" runserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a command on the command prompt, it is necessary to provide the correct path to the file.

Let's pretend you have your django files stored in a folder with the following path:

`C:\my_stuff\subfolder\django_project >`

Presume that when you run the `dir` command (the Windows analog to the `ls` command you mention in your question) it might show something like this:

`C:\my_stuff\subfolder\django_project > dir`

```
blog
db.sqlite3
manage.py
mysite
```

If you were to then run your command:

`C:\my_stuff\subfolder\django_project > python manage.py runserver`

Everything should work fine. But if you are in a different directory, you will get the error you describe. For example, this will fail.

`C:\my_stuff\subfolder > python manage.py runserver`

If, for some reason, your Windows command prompt does not show you which directory you are in, you can run the `cd` command to confirm where you are.

An alternate method is to point the `python` interpreter to the location of the manage.py script, by providing the path:

`C:\my_stuff\subfolder > python django_project\manage.py runserver`

But this sometimes introduces subtle problems, because scripts like manage.py might be written with the expectation that they will be run from the directory they are stored in. Your mileage may vary.